# Syntax error near 'rows FROM `#__whmportfolio_item` AS a WHERE a.cate in (4)' at line 1

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

I have moved the site from server that have mysql server to other one that have MariaDB server version also the site was working without issue on the old server

But on new one I got this error :

> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'rows FROM `#__whmportfolio_item` AS a WHERE a.cate in (4)' at
>   line 1

this is the helper cod of the module:

```
<?php

    class ModWhmPortfolioHelper
    {
        public static function toggleVoteAjax() {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $u = WhmportfolioFrontendHelper::getUid();
        $pfid = JRequest::getInt('pfid', 0);
        if(!$pfid) {
            return null;
        }
        $rs = $db
        ->setQuery("SELECT id FROM #__whmportfolio_liked WHERE u = '{$u}'")
        ->loadObject();
        if(is_null($rs)) {
            $db
            ->setQuery("INSERT INTO #__whmportfolio_liked(pfid, u) VALUES ({$pfid}, '{$u}')")
            ->execute();
        }
        else {
            $db
            ->setQuery("DELETE FROM #__whmportfolio_liked WHERE id = {$rs->id}")
            ->execute();
        }

        return $db
        ->setQuery("SELECT count(*) as c FROM #__whmportfolio_liked WHERE u = '{$u}'")
        ->loadObject()->c;
    }

    public static function getItems($cate, $tag, $offset, $limit, $isize='0x0'){
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $uid = WhmportfolioFrontendHelper::getUid();
        $where = "";
        if($tag || $cate) {
            $where = "WHERE ";
            if($tag) {
                $tag = implode(',', $tag);
                $where .= "a.tag in ({$tag})";
            }
            if($tag && $cate) {
                $where .= " AND ";
            }
            if($cate) {
                $cate = implode(',', $cate);
                $where .= "a.cate in ({$cate})";
            }
        }
        $q = 'SELECT DISTINCT a.*,'.
            "(select count(*) from #__whmportfolio_liked as l where l.pfid = a.id) as cliked,".
            "(select count(*) from #__whmportfolio_liked as l where l.u = '{$uid}') as lactive
            FROM `#__whmportfolio_item` AS a
            {$where}
            ORDER BY a.id DESC";
        $rs = $db->setQuery($q, $offset, $limit)->loadObjectList();
        if(is_null($rs)) return 0;

        foreach($rs as &$item) {
            WhmportfolioFrontendHelper::build($item, $isize);    
        }

        $q = "SELECT DISTINCT count(*) as rows FROM `#__whmportfolio_item` AS a {$where}";
        return (object)array('items'=>$rs, 'total'=>$db->setQuery($q)->loadObject()->rows);
    }


    }

?>
```

Comment: print and share the query.. I mean value of $q. `$q = "SELECT DISTINCT count(*) as rows FROM `#__whmportfolio_item` AS a {$where}";`

Comment: how can i do it because whene i try print_r($q); it show onlye the syntax error above

Comment: What is the complete query? Just would like to see.

Comment: can you please give me an examle on on the cod above how can i make it more secure from injections ?

Answer (score 0):

`#` introduces a comment that lasts until the end of the line.

In order to have `#` in a table name, quote it using backtics:

```
  ->setQuery("DELETE FROM `#__whmportfolio_liked` WHERE id = {$rs->id}")
                          ^                     ^
```